# Grid search with LightGBM example

Tags: python-3.x, grid-search, lightgbm

I am trying to find the best parameters for a `lightgbm` model using `GridSearchCV` from `sklearn.model_selection`. I have not been able to find a solution that actually works.

I have managed to set up a partly working code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

np.random.seed(1)

train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
y = pd.read_csv('y.csv')
y = y.values.ravel()
print(train.shape, test.shape, y.shape)

categoricals = ['COL_A','COL_B']
indexes_of_categories = [train.columns.get_loc(col) for col in categoricals]

gkf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42).split(X=train, y=y)

param_grid = {
    'num_leaves': [31, 127],
    'reg_alpha': [0.1, 0.5],
    'min_data_in_leaf': [30, 50, 100, 300, 400],
    'lambda_l1': [0, 1, 1.5],
    'lambda_l2': [0, 1]
    }

lgb_estimator = lgb.LGBMClassifier(boosting_type='gbdt',  objective='binary', num_boost_round=2000, learning_rate=0.01, metric='auc',categorical_feature=indexes_of_categories)

gsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator=lgb_estimator, param_grid=param_grid, cv=gkf)
lgb_model = gsearch.fit(X=train, y=y)

print(lgb_model.best_params_, lgb_model.best_score_)
```

This seems to be working but with a `UserWarning`:

> `categorical_feature` keyword has been found in `params` and will be
>   ignored. Please use `categorical_feature` argument of the Dataset
>   constructor to pass this parameter.

I am looking for a working solution or perhaps a suggestion on how to ensure that lightgbm accepts categorical arguments in the above code

Comment: may I ask, is there a reason why a scoring function is omitted in the GridSearchCV?

Comment: you would be better off using lightgbm's default api for crossvalidation (lgb.cv) instead of GridSearchCV, as you can use early_stopping_rounds in lgb.cv.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the warning states, `categorical_feature` is not one of the `LGBMModel` arguments. It is relevant in `lgb.Dataset` instantiation, which in the case of sklearn API is done directly in the `fit()` method [see the doc](http://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html#lightgbm.LGBMModel.fit). Thus, in order to pass those in the `GridSearchCV` optimisation one has to provide it as an argument of the `GridSearchCV.fit()` method in the case of sklearn v0.19.1 or as an additional `fit_params` argument in `GridSearchCV` instantiation in older sklearn versions

Comment: Small world, your Kaggle kernel was also very helpful !! :)

Comment: i'm happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you are struggling with how to pass the fit_params, which happened to me as well, this is how you should do that:

```
fit_params = {'categorical_feature':indexes_of_categories}
clf = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, cv=n_folds)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train, **fit_params)
```